# Mounting NAS drive with cifs using credentials file through fstab does not work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, server-message-block, cifs

I can mount the drive in the following way, no problem there:

```
mount -t cifs //nas/home /mnt/nas -o username=username,password=pass\!word,uid=1000,gid=100,rw,suid
```

However if I try to mount it via fstab I get the following error:

```
//nas/home /mnt/nas cifs  iocharset=utf8,credentials=/home/username/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,gid=100  0        0 auto
```

.smbcredentials file looks like this:

```
username=username
password=pass\!word
```

Note the ! in my password ... which I am escaping in both instances

I also made sure there are no eol in the file using `:set noeol binary` from [Mount CIFS Credentials File has Special Character](https://serverfault.com/questions/309429/mount-cifs-credentials-file-has-special-character)

`chmod` on .credentials file is `0600` and `chown` is `root:root` file is under `~/`

Why am I getting in on the one side and not with fstab??

I am running on ubuntu 12 LTE and mount.cifs -V gives me mount.cifs version: 5.1

Any help and suggestions would be appreciated ...

**UPDATE:**
`/var/log/syslog` shows following

```
[26630.509396] Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
[26630.509407] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
[26630.509528] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
```

**UPDATE no 2**

Debugging with strace
mount through fstab:

```
strace -f -e trace=mount mount -a
Process 4984 attached
Process 4983 suspended
Process 4985 attached
Process 4984 suspended
Process 4984 resumed
Process 4985 detached
[pid  4984] --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid  4984] mount("//nas/home", ".", "cifs", 0, "ip=<internal ip>,unc=\\\\nas\\home"...) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
Process 4983 resumed
Process 4984 detached
```

Mount through terminal

```
strace -f -e trace=mount mount -t cifs //nas/home /mnt/nas -o username=user,password=pass\!wd,uid=1000,gid=100,rw,suid
Process 4990 attached
Process 4989 suspended
Process 4991 attached
Process 4990 suspended
Process 4990 resumed
Process 4991 detached
[pid  4990] --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
[pid  4990] mount("//nas/home", ".", "cifs", 0, "ip=<internal ip>,unc=\\\\nas\\home"...) = 0
Process 4989 resumed
Process 4990 detached
```

Comment: Unless you have a typo in your post you are not escaping the `!` in both cases. The escape character is the backslash `\ `, not the forward slash `/`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the heads up. It is only a typo here! Obviously I used the \ char to escape ;-).

Comment: Are you sure the password should be escaped in the credentials file? It's a shell metachar, which is why it has to be escaped on the command line but how will it be misinterpreted in the credentials file without escaping? Also I can't see any error message in your post, just command to mount and a line from fstab, no error message.

Comment: ptman I tried both, escaped and unescaped versions, I think it never gets to read the file. how could I check that?

Comment: you can check for open() and read() syscalls using strace

Comment: ptman I never get a file open when mounting through fstab, I tried moving the file to /etc and giving it 777 permission to see if I get any call, but for some reason I got no open() or read(). I have never used strace so there might be the problem, any help with that?

Comment: ptman As you can see in the strace calls, it is an authentication problem ...

Comment: you are asking strace to not show open calls, try using `-e trace=open,read` instead or leave `-e trace` out and direct the output to a file that you can examine afterwards.

Comment: also try giving the `-o credentials=$file` to mount when calling on the command line instead of `-o username=...,password=...`, so that the two calls are as close to each other as possible

Comment: BINGO looks like it was /n in my credentials file that was causing the problem!!! WORKS NOW THANKS A BUNCH PTMAN!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a typo of the variable *username* that I missed. Somehow the **s** was missing as you can see from the strace call:

```
 [pid 5240] getgid32() = 0 [pid 5240] access("/etc/smbcredentials", R_OK) = 0 [pid 5240]
 open("/etc/smbcredentials", O_RDONLY) = 3 
 [pid 5240] fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777,st_size=41, ...}) = 0 
 [pid 5240] mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb77d0000 
 [pid 5240] read(3, "uername=username\npassword=password"..., 4096) = 41 –
```